# How to decode in JavaScript a URL encoded in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, backbone-routing

I'm using PHP to encode a Url and after that I'm using the Url in Javascript for filling the title of a Bootstrap modal

I have something like this when I encode in PHP

`#task/2013-12-23/517/1+task+for+Some+other+test+apartment+in+Lviv+on+December+23rd+2013`

but the decode in Javascript is expecting this

`#task/2013-12-23/517/1%20task%20for%20Some%20other%20test%20apartment%20in%20Lviv%20on%20December%2023rd%202013`

I dont want to do it like this

```
var title = "1+task+for+Some+other+test+apartment+in+Lviv+on+December+23rd+2013";
title.replace(/\+/g," ");
```

Anyone knows a better solution?

Comment: decodeURI or decodeURIComponent

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't think there's a better solution than replacing the + character. The thing is that PHP's `urlencode` follows a different standard. You could try using `rawurlencode` on the PHP side to get `%20`...

Comment: Yes, I dont want to replace "+" for " " , I want to use decodeURIComponent in Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `rawurlencode()` instead of `urlencode`

Answer (score -1):

You solution is good. You could use

```
var decodedTitle = title.replace("+"," ");
```

But it is more of the same.

Comment: Read the question please, I know how to replace stuff in a javascript string, thats's not the issue